# As a manager would you hire a very high-rep SO user, knowing that he would spend most of the time on SO?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Stack Overflow reputation marketable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30578/is-stack-overflow-reputation-marketable)

Would the bugger make a suitable investment for a busy company,
knowing that he would spend most of is time on SO?

Comment: @Pekka: how can a person be productive if they spend most of their work hours on SO?

Comment: Well, [somebody](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/04/03/google-here-i-come.aspx) seems to think he is a suitable investment

Comment: @Kop I really doubt whether he really spends "most" of his working time on SO (in terms of the net amount of time.) But I don't know of course... I personally would just be damn irritated about being the object of such slightly insulting questions, and brain-dead answers like the one below.  But that's probably just the price of being a  celebrity :)

Comment: @Pekka: The specific details (inc. TZ and times of the day) were made public some time ago - seek and you shall find. (Anyway, I wonder how much is the OP willing to offer...esp.in *that* case)

Comment: Effective time-management is a trait of any good employee

Comment: @Pekka: no one mentioned Jon Skeet until balpha's answer, which came after our comments

Comment: @Kop take a look at the first revision of the question

Comment: @Pekka thanks for your last comment.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25453/has-anyone-ever-used-their-gained-reputation-points-to-get-a-job-or-something

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to consider that the [user with the second-highest rep on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) was [hired](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/) by the company that knows better than anyone else just how much time he spends on the site. And he was not hired to answer questions.

Answer (score 6):

I question this statement:

> knowing that he would spend most of is time on SO?

I was ranked #5 on StackOverflow at one point about a year ago, but I got there because of a highly-disfunctional work situation where I ended up putting far too much time into SO.  I have since remedied the situation and now have a job that allows me to be productive for my actual employer. (BTW - nothing against my previous employer, I just wasn't a good fit there).

The result is my Stack Overflow participation is (sadly) way down. I've dropped about a dozen spots already.  It's not zero - I still browse and answer questions at work.  It's just now at a more-appropriate level.

The point is that hiring a high-rep Stack Overflow user doesn't guarantee you'll lose all their productivity to SO.  It's more likely that either: 1) there's a good reason they're on the job market *or* 2) they really are just that good.  Either way, a high reputation is a big positive for that user.  Of course, they could just be a goof-off, but that's what interviews are for - so you can find that kind of thing out before hiring them.

Comment: In other words: the job needs to be more interesting than SO. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yup. I would then keep him on a workstation without a connection to the internet or SO. That would kill him

Comment: Because killing new hires *really* makes them productive...!

Comment: Sarcasm is obviously lost on you people :-)

Comment: @Vedran, you can get jokes/sarcasm and just not think they're funny.

Comment: @Popular Demand agree with you too. @Vedran :)

Comment: @abel, FYI, only the first "@-style name" in a comment sets off the notifier, so Vedran won't get notified of your comment (or this one).

Comment: @Popular Demand thanks for letting me know